# Problem with instaling GRUB/LILO in dual boot with windows 10 UEFI/GPT

Tags: debian, grub, uefi, gpt

I am having some issues when trying to install Debian 9 alongside Windows 10.

Everything goes smoothly until the GRUB installation comes up. After I pick the partition it starts to install and after a while it says that installation is failed (without specifying the issue). Same for LILO.

I searched the internet and found out it may be some issue with UEFI or the fact that my disc is GPT but couldn't find the solution. Does anyone know what may be the issue and how to solve it?

Please note that I am not an experienced user and have a little knowledge about this kind of stuff. Also, my ultimate goal is to have Linux for running [LAMMPS](http://lammps.sandia.gov/download.html) alongside windows 10 which is already installed (it is my business computer).

So I would prefer to make least modification possible. I have chosen Debian since I was working on it before.

I can add that I have two drives, one SDD with windows on it and one HDD (empty). If anyone knows the issue and needs additional information I will be happy to provide them.

Comment: When installing Debian , create a small partition size = 1M (flag it `bios_boot`) allowing you to install Grub on the GPT table.

Answer (score 0):

For UEFI/GPT dual, I'd recommend using [rEFInd boot manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/), you can add as many operating systems as you want. This will include live USB flashdrive OS to the rEFInd boot menu and along with other amazing features.